# Чтение в дерево (TreeSet) 5 целых чисел и вывод наименьшего

Tags: java, дерево

В программе имеется дерево (TreeSet) с именем tree. Необходимо выполнить в него чтение с клавиатуры 5-и целых чисел и вывести наименьший (последний по величине) элемент.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        TreeSet<Integer> tree = new TreeSet<>();
        //YOUR CODE will be placed HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ну как то так**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class ArrayTestStackOverFlow {

    private static final int countNumber = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Integer number;

        TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();

        // Заполняем дерево числами с клавиатуры
        for (int i = 0; i < countNumber; i++) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            treeSet.add(number);
        }

        // Получаем искомое число
        System.out.println(treeSet.first());

    }

}
```